# Meaning of "var lthis = this, someObj" in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to Javascript and I have difficulty in understanding a statement written in javascript. The statement is

`var lthis = this,  someObj`

Any sort of help will be appreciated. If there are pointers/name of the topic to understand this will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's declaring two variables (`lthis` and `someObj`) and initializing one of them by assigning `this` to it.

It's exactly the same as this:

```
var lthis;
var someObj;

lthis = this;
```

> If there are pointers/name of the topic to understand this will be great.

There's no shortage of JavaScript tutorials and such if you search. David Flanagan's *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* is decent, and there's a *lot* of stuff on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript). [Marijn Haverbeke's *Eloquent JavaScript* book and site](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) are very well-reviewed (I haven't read it myself).

Comment: Oh ok! That is easy :-) I was thinking too much. Thanks Crowder.

Answer (score 0):

By the way `var lthis = this` is to access **this** in a different scope.

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sv7nq/7/)

```
var MyClass = function(){
    var that = this;
    this.myVar = "hello";


    $("#my-span2").click(function(){
        // returns undefined  because "this" refer 
        //to the DOM element
        alert(this.myVar);
    })  

    $("#my-span").click(function(){
        //returns "hello" because "that" refer to "this" (var that = this) 
        //which refer to MyClass instance
        alert(that.myVar);
    })



}

var myClass = new MyClass();
```